# Java 8 Streams: map in stages

Tags: selenium, java-8, java-stream

Is it possible to carry out mappings on a stream in stages without creating intermediary collections?

I'm working with Selenium and mapping streams of `WebElement`s. It's important to do them in batches to avoid `StaleReferenceException` being thrown since the page dynamically updates itself and some of the `map` operations take a relatively long time to complete.

Problem (simplified):

```
public class StreamTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] input = new String[] {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5"};
        List<String> list = map(input).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    private static Stream<String> map(String[] input) {
        return Arrays.stream(input).parallel()
                .map(s -> {
                    String ret = s + "0";
                    System.out.println(String.format("%10s%10s", s, ret));
                    return ret;
                })
                .map(s -> {
                    String ret = s + "0";
                    System.out.println(String.format("%10s%10s", s, ret));
                    return ret;
                })
                .map(s -> {
                    String ret = s + "0";
                    System.out.println(String.format("%10s%10s", s, ret));
                    return ret;
                });
    }
}
```

Sample Output:

```
         3        30
         4        40
        30       300
         1        10
         5        50
        10       100
         2        20
        50       500
       300      3000
        40       400
       500      5000
        20       200
       100      1000
       400      4000
       200      2000
```

Desired output:

```
         1        10
         2        20
         3        30
         4        40
         5        50
        10       100
        20       200
        30       300
        40       400
        50       500
       100      1000
       200      2000
       300      3000
       400      4000
       500      5000
```

Current Solution:

```
private static Stream<String> map(String[] input) {
    return Arrays.stream(input)
            .map(s -> s + "0")
            .collect(Collectors.toList()).stream()              
            .map(s -> s + "0")
            .collect(Collectors.toList()).stream()
            .map(s -> s + "0");
}
```

Is there a way to achieve this without creating a dummy collection between each call to `map`?

Note: I need to use a stream with *n* calls to `map` rather than a sequence of *n* for-loops.

Comment: In your example, you don't need to call `.collect(Collectors.toList()).stream()`. Post your real code here and I will help you

Comment: How you handle dealing with these collections will vary widely depending on what you are actually trying to do. Post your actual code that uses Selenium and WebElements or remove the [selenium] tag.

Comment: I recommend using plain old for-loops. You could do the mapping in each iteration in-place in the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not how streams have been designed to behave.

A sequence of map operations is applied without creating intermediate collections, only the terminal operation decides what the result will be (a collection or a single value).

But to work in batches (applying the first map operation to all input, then applying the second map operation to all first intermediate results, and so on ) you need intermediate collections.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work:

```
String[] input = new String[] {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5"};

Stream.of("", "0", "00")
      .flatMap(suffix -> Stream.of(input)
           .map(prefix -> prefix + suffix)
           .map(s -> String.format("%10s%10s", s, s + "0")))
      .forEach(System.out::println);
```

The bad ordering is due to the `parallel()` call, which can probably be avoided.

Comment: don't know exactly what the OP wants, but if you collect your result instead of `forEach` (that should probably be `forEachOrdered`), you would get a result != that OP wants. After collecting the OP wants to get `1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000` - if I understood it correctly

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, no idea what you are trying to do. Here is something that would conform to your sample output:

```
private static Stream<String> map(String[] input) {

    return Stream.of("", "0", "00")
            .flatMap(x -> Arrays.stream(input)
                    .map(y -> y + x)
                    .peek(z -> System.out.println(z + " " + z + "0"))
                    .map(z -> z + "0"))
            .skip(2 * input.length);
}
```

The out of order results that you see are because you are using `parallel` and *intermediate* operations have no defined order of execution, only *terminal* do (unless otherwise stated - `forEach` for example)